# What is `distributionStatisticExpiry` and `distributionStatisticBufferLength` in micrometer java lib?

Tags: java, datadog, percentile, micrometer, statsd

We use `Timer` from `StatsdMeterRegistry` to track the remote API requests duration (p95 percentile). From the JavaDocs not really clear how `distributionStatisticExpiry` and `distributionStatisticBufferLength` would affect on Data Dog charts. Not really understand about how "Ring Buffers" used in micrometer but the `distributionStatisticExpiry` seems the period of time in which the maximum percentile value is determined.

*e.g. if 95% of requests <= 1sec within 1 minute of `distributionStatisticExpiry`, then the value of p95 would be 1 second during that minute on the graph.*

Is this right? And what `distributionStatisticBufferLength` means in this case?

Also, if we have high load on particular service (more then 500 rps) would it be appropriate to use `distributionStatisticExpiry` value like 5 seconds and what `distributionStatisticBufferLength`?